# Customize the user interface in Azure Active Directory B2C custom policy

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

My organization needs passwordless with email authentication in sign in. I tried [this sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/passwordless-email) & it worked for me.I want to customize the UI and add branding page instead of default page. i follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-overview) documentation but not getting the oevrall process.
how can i customize the UI and background image.

Comment: What are you not getting about the article, please be more specific? You reference your own HTML which provides all the content to style the page, with an empty div element which b2c will insert its form into.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-ui-customization-custom i am ising custom policy so following this.
i am geeting error which uploading policy with these change.

Comment: What error do you get?